# WCF Host taking long time to start when machine connected to network

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, performance

We have created a small WCF test project in order to test and isolate this problem.

We are running Windows 7 64bit and Visual Studio 2008.

- When we press F5 to run, it takes about 10 seconds to start the WCF host.
- If we remove the network cable and press F5, it takes less than 1 second to start.
- If we turn on the wireless network it also takes less than 1 second to start.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

**Edit**

We have now tested this with Visual Studio 2010, this does not have the same problem. So it could be a bug in the Visual Studio 2008 WCF host.

**Edit 2**

We have now checked this on a different network, no problem. So it appears to be a combination of Visual Studio 2008 and a specific network.